# if else for .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i'm looking for a way to set RewriteBase in my .htaccess depending on if my web runs locally or live.

it should be something like:

```
if(localhost) RewriteBase /mylocalweb/
if(www.mydomain.com) RewriteBase /
```

any ideas how to do it?
thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813554/how-would-i-write-an-if-elseif-elseif-conditional-block-in-an-htaccess-file for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use RewriteCond in front of your RewriteRule instead of fiddling with RewriteBase

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond